# How do I sort a column that contains two divs with jQuery Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, sorting, html, tablesorter

I'm using [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to sort a table. One of my columns looks like this:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <span class="green">Yes</span> <a href="##">(unverify)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <span class="red">No<>/a> <a href="##">(verify)</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

In other words, there's two divs, one to show **Yes** in green with a link, and the other to show **No** in red with a link. One of the divs is always hidden, and the two are toggled whenever the user clicks on the link.

jQuery  Tablesorter cannot sort on this column. Is there a way to get it to do so, or do I have to modify the HTML to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`textExtraction`](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html) callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // define a custom text extraction function 
        textExtraction: function(node) { 
          // check you're at the right column
          if ($(node).find('.green').length == 1) {
            // extract data from markup and return it  
            return $(node).find('div:not(.hidden)').find('span').text();;
          }
          else {
            return $(node).text();
          }
        } 
    }); 
});
```

I haven't tested that but it should work in theory

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In my case, the code in `textExtraction` was `return $(node).find('div:not(.hidden)').find('span').text();`

Comment: Oi, I just realized that this applies the `textExtraction` function to ALL the columns. Any way to apply it to only one column in a table? I want the other columns to sort using the default sorter, since those columns are working fine.

Comment: @DanielT., the custom parser method in my answer is pretty much the same thing, but allows you to specify which columns to apply it to.

Comment: I've updated the code a little above to include your text selector and to return just the default text from the cell if jQuery doesn't find anything with a class of `green` in the node's content...could you try that?

Comment: I've forked a copy of the [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) plugin and added the ability to apply the [textExtraction to specific columns](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html)... just so you know ;)

Comment: Can't I declare textExtraction for SPECIFIC column ?

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to look into creating a [custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html).  its pretty simple, you just specify how to interpret the value in the cell by passing in a function to the format field.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to sort any type of column, no matter how the content is complex:
add 'sorted' attribute to the , fill 'sorted' value in the server side according to the preffered order, (which is easier than in javascript).

e.g.

```
<td sorter='1'> 
    <div> 
        <span class="green">Yes</span> <a href="##">(unverify)</a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="hidden"> 
        <span class="red">No<>/a> <a href="##">(verify)</a> 
    </div> 
</td>
<td sorter='2'> 
    <div  class="hidden"> > 
        <span class="green">Yes</span> <a href="##">(unverify)</a> 
    </div> 
    <div>
        <span class="red">No<>/a> <a href="##">(verify)</a> 
    </div> 
</td>
```

then add the following code in $(function ()

```
$("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
   textExtraction: function(node){                    
           return $(node).attr("sorter");                
   }
});
```